# latexindent: it does the work, but emits these messages

Tags: latexindent

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE document}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 677.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1047.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1073.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1199.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1220.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*(\$)?\\begin{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1621.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\end{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1682.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\end{ <-- HERE table}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1621, <MAINFILE> line 1.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\end{ <-- HERE tabular}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1621, <MAINFILE> line 6.
```

It must be something silly I do. But what is it?

### **update**

Here is my `localSettings.yaml` file:

```
# Default value of indentation
defaultIndent: "  "

# remove trailing whitespace from all lines 
removeTrailingWhitespace: 1

#  verbatim environments- environments specified 
#  in this hash table will not be changed at all!
# vim: +2,/^\s*$/-1!column -t | sort -u | awk '{print "\t" $0}'
verbatimEnvironments:
    ADA:                  1
    algorithmic:          1
    AWKPROG:              1
    CEEPL:                1
    code:                 1
    Code:                 1
    CPLUSPLUS:            1
    EIFFEL:               1
    EMEL:                 1
    EMELRESPONSE:         1
    JAVA:                 1
    lcode:                1
    lCode:                1
    lola:                 1
    LOLA:                 1
    LolaCodeTcbListing:   1
    LolaCodeTcbListing*:  1
    lstlisting:           1
    OCCAM:                1
    PASCAL:               1
    PYTHON:               1
    sample:               1
    Sample:               1
    session:              1
    verbatim:             1

# no indent blocks (not necessarily verbatim environments) which are marked as
# %\begin{noindent} or anything else that the user puts in this hash table
noIndentBlock:
    noindent: 1
    cmhtest: 1

# if you don't want to have additional indentation in an environment put it in
# this hash table; note that environments in this hash table will inherit the
# *current* level of indentation they just won't get any *additional*.
# vim: +2,/^\s*$/-1!column -t | sort -u | awk '{print "\t" $0}'
noAdditionalIndent:
    frame:               1

indentAfterHeading:
    part :
      indent : 0
      level : 1
    chapter :
      indent : 0
      level : 2
    section :
      indent : 0
      level : 3

# vim: +2,/^\s*$/-1!column -t | sort -u | awk '{print "\t" $0}'
indentAfterItems:
    description:  1
    enumerate:    1
    itemize:      1

# vim: +2,/^\s*$/-1!column -t | sort -u | awk '{print "\t" $0}'
constructIfElseFi:
    if@fast:       1
    ifnum:         1
    ifodd:         1
    @ifundefined:  1

# vim: +2,/^\s*$/-1!column -t | sort -u | awk '{print "\t" $0}'
lookForAlignDelims:
    align:      1
    align*:     1
    alignat:    1
    alignat*:   1
    aligned:    1
    array:      1
    bmatrix:    1
    cases:      1
    dcases:     1
    eqnarray:   1
    eqnarray*:  1
    listabla:   1
    longtable:  1
    matrix:     1
    pmatrix:    1
    tabular:    1
    tabularx:   1
```

Input is, say, a file named `input.tex`:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\end{itemize}
```

While the output upon running `latexindent -l input.tex` is:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;     marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE document}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 677.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1047.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1073.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1199.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1220.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*(\$)?\\begin{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1621.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\end{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1682.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\end{ <-- HERE itemize}/ at /opt/texbin/latexindent line 1621, <MAINFILE> line 1.
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
\end{itemize}
```

**UPDATE**
I manually edited the source, and it solves this problem. But others pop out:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE document}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 677.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1047.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*%\*\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1073.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\end{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1199.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^%\s*\\begin{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1220.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*(\$)?\\begin{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1621.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\s*\\end{ <-- HERE \\?(.*?)}/ at /home/yogi/bin/latexindent line 1682.
```

This happens for `/home/yogi/bin/latexindent` being the one downloaded from the [git repository](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/blob/master/latexindent.pl).

Comment: do you have an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for this?

Comment: How is this a complete MWE?

Comment: Can you please give us some more context? Without a crystal ball it is really difficult to help you.

Comment: This might be a perl bug see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753737/deprecated-left-curly-bracket-in-perl-regex-exactly-when  they added a warning but it was too aggressive and warned in good cases too, it got fixed but it depends which perl version you have.

Comment: Apologies for this, was fixed a while ago in develop, hoping for a major release later in 2016

Comment: for reference, see https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues/21#issue-52050472

Comment: Not an issue in version 3.0 either, available Feb 2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replicate the warnings, just type `latexindent` in a terminal.

It's a warning given by the fact that the `{` character in the regex expressions used in the perl script `latexindent.pl` should be escaped as per [this perl deprecation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod#A_literal_%22%7B%22_should_now_be_escaped_in_a_pattern).

To correct the issues, just escape the opening brackets in the lines stated in the warnings. For example the line 677:

```
if(m/^\s*\\begin{document}/)
```

should be modified to:

```
if(m/^\s*\\begin\{document}/)
```

and so on.

The warnings can be ignored but they will become syntax errors starting perl v5.26.

Comment: Just to confirm that this was fixed a while ago in the develop branch; hoping for a major release in late 2016

Comment: This was fixed in [March 29th, 2016](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/commit/ce8113329500adb5a65cbccbd9192a05a74f9842), and has been released as [version 2.2](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/pull/49).